# $O$ space/time calculation for SVD algorithm

Tags: matrices, algorithms, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I recently started studying the SVD and I was given the following

- [Fast Monte Carlo algorithms for matrices II: computing a low-rank approximation to a matrix](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/pdrineas/documents/publications/Drineas_SICOMP_06b.pdf) (2006) [PDF]

I can understand the main goal of the paper and how the algorithms are implemented but I have problem in understanding the calculation of $O (\cdot)$.For example, on page 9 it says  that the algorithm needs $O(cm+c^2)$ additional space and $O(c^{2}m+c^{3})$ additional time.

It would be really helpful if someone could explain the calculation of $O (\cdot)$ in that algorithm in order to get used to calculate them on my own.

Comment: What are $c$ and $m$?

Comment: c is the number of columns that are chosen randomly from n colums  of matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ in order to construct a need matrix $C\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times c}$, m is just the number of rows.

Comment: The analysis of the implementation is in section 4.2

Comment: @ Metahominid , I've already studied it , but I'm confused because I take different result for space complexity.$$O(mck)+O(c)+O(cm)+O(cm)=O(mck)+O(cm)$$